# How to get href links from a webpage using Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape all .pdf links, title of the pdfs and time when it was received on this [webpage](https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/ann.html?scrip=532538). In my attempt to find href links from the page, I have tried the following code-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/ann.html?scrip=532538').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print(link.attrs['href'])
```

I am getting the following output-

```
{{CorpannData.Table[0].NSURL}}
{{CorpannData.Table[0].NSURL}}
#
/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachLive/{{cann.ATTACHMENTNAME}}
/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachHis/{{cann.ATTACHMENTNAME}}
/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachLive/{{CorpannDataByNewsId[0].ATTACHMENTNAME}}
/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachHis/{{CorpannDataByNewsId[0].ATTACHMENTNAME}}
```

My desired output is getting all pdf links like this:

```
https://www.bseindia.com/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachHis/e525dbbb-5ec1-4327-a5ea-9662c66f32a5.pdf

https://www.bseindia.com/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachHis/d2355247-3287-4c41-be61-2a5655276e79.pdf
```

**(Optional)** My desired output for overall program is-

```
Title: Compliances-Reg. 39 (3) - Details of Loss of Certificate / Duplicate Certificate
Exchange received time: 19-12-2019 13:49:14 
PDF link: https://www.bseindia.com/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachHis/e525dbbb-5ec1-4327-a5ea-9662c66f32a5.pdf
...
```

and to have the program look for new updates on the webpage every second.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
r = requests.get(
    'https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/AnnGetData/w?strCat=-1&strPrevDate=&strScrip=532538&strSearch=A&strToDate=&strType=C').json()

data = []
for item in r['Table']:
    if item['News_submission_dt'] is None:
        item['News_submission_dt'] = "N/A"
    else:
        item['News_submission_dt'] = item['News_submission_dt'].replace(
            "T", " ")
    if len(item['ATTACHMENTNAME']) == 0:
        item['ATTACHMENTNAME'] = "N/A"
    else:
        item['ATTACHMENTNAME'] = f"https://www.bseindia.com/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachHis/{item['ATTACHMENTNAME']}"

    item = item['NEWSSUB'], item[
        'News_submission_dt'], item['ATTACHMENTNAME']
    print(
        f"Title: {item[0]}\nExchange received time: {item[1]}\nPDF: {item[2]}")
```

Output:

```
Title: Compliances-Reg. 39 (3) - Details of Loss of Certificate / Duplicate Certificate
Exchange received time: 2019-12-19 13:49:14
PDF: https://www.bseindia.com/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachHis/e525dbbb-5ec1-4327-a5ea-9662c66f32a5.pdf
Title: Compliances-Reg. 39 (3) - Details of Loss of Certificate / Duplicate Certificate
Exchange received time: 2019-12-16 15:48:22
PDF: https://www.bseindia.com/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachHis/d2355247-3287-4c41-be61-2a5655276e79.pdf
Title: Announcement under Regulation 30 (LODR)-Analyst / Investor Meet - Intimation
Exchange received time: 2019-12-16 09:50:00
PDF: https://www.bseindia.com/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachHis/6d7ba756-a541-4c85-b711-7270db7cb003.pdf
Title: Allotment Of Non-Convertible Debentures
Exchange received time: 2019-12-11 16:44:33
PDF: https://www.bseindia.com/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachHis/cdb18e51-725f-43ac-b01f-89f322ae2f5b.pdf
Title: Lntimation Regarding Change Of Name Of Karvy Fintech Private Limited, Registrar & Transfer Agents
Exchange received time: 2019-12-09 15:48:49
PDF: https://www.bseindia.com/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachHis/9dd527d7-d39d-422d-8de8-c428c24e169e.pdf
Title: Compliances-Reg. 39 (3) - Details of Loss of Certificate / Duplicate Certificate
Exchange received time: 2019-12-05 14:44:23
PDF: https://www.bseindia.com/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachHis/38af1a6e-a597-47e7-85b8-b620a961df84.pdf
Title: Compliances-Reg. 39 (3) - Details of Loss of Certificate / Duplicate Certificate
```

And So On...

Output to `CSV` file:

```py
import requests
import csv

r = requests.get(
    'https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/AnnGetData/w?strCat=-1&strPrevDate=&strScrip=532538&strSearch=A&strToDate=&strType=C').json()

data = []
for item in r['Table']:
    if item['News_submission_dt'] is None:
        item['News_submission_dt'] = "N/A"
    else:
        item['News_submission_dt'] = item['News_submission_dt'].replace(
            "T", " ")
    if len(item['ATTACHMENTNAME']) == 0:
        item['ATTACHMENTNAME'] = "N/A"
    else:
        item['ATTACHMENTNAME'] = f"https://www.bseindia.com/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachHis/{item['ATTACHMENTNAME']}"

    item = item['NEWSSUB'], item[
        'News_submission_dt'], item['ATTACHMENTNAME']
    # print(
    #     f"Title: {item[0]}\nExchange received time: {item[1]}\nPDF: {item[2]}")
    data.append(item)

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline="", encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Title', 'Exchange Received Time', 'PDF Link'])
    writer.writerows(data)
```

([Copy of the CSV file](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/b9c00d26ac00a22a2bb12d16a83307ad/output.csv))